# I installed JDK and added path variable but still i am facing -> zsh : command not found: jdk in macOS

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, macos-catalina

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrdWO.png)

I tried giving this path variable but didn't seem to work

`export $JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home`

Then I tried this, and seem to work

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

but still facing jdk command not found issue

Basically, I m trying to install chromedriver using

`sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver`

but I'm facing this error

Comment: There is no `jdk` command. Maybe you mean `java`?

Comment: @Bhumika why/how are you using apt on MacOS?

Comment: This is a classic X/Y Problem (xyproblem.info). You should describe the root cause you're facing, not the problem you think you're facing. In a comment below, you give the actual error is when trying to use `apt` to install something. `apt` is not a MacOS command! The error you're getting is a red herring. Use `brew cask install chromedriver` instead to install chromedriver

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I'm. sorry as I thought JDK was the issue causing to install a chrome driver(updated version). I'm newbie to mac, I was installed firefox driver but it didn't scrape few pages as it took time to load, so I added javascript in my selenium python code (scrappy-project) ```driver.execute_script("return document.readyState==\"complete\";")``` but it still didn't scrape some of the pages as it took time to load.

Comment: (continue...) so I saw somewhere in StackOverflow to use chrome driver(with headless)as it is faster.   I have also already installed with ```brew cask install chromedriver``` but now I'm facing this error ```raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chrome driver``` So I have been trying to install JDK with ```apt```

Answer (score 1):

`jdk` is not a command. The basic commands you probably want are `javac` to compile your code and `java` to run it.

Comment: I m trying install chrome driver using ```sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver```
but i m facing this error 

```Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)```

I m facing this error  but this is the right path